# Max. data-transfer-rate for RPi 3 over Wifi

Tags: pi-3, wifi, hostapd

**Q1** What is the maximum data-tranfer-rate for the RPi 3B onboard wifi as access point?

**Q1.1** If it's > 72 Mb/s what does the config for hostapd.conf look like?

Comment: What have you tried? There are tons of available tutorials that does exactly that. Isn't a Google search faster than posting a question on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com!?

Comment: @BinarWeb Your are right there are tons of material out there and I tried some of them but was not able to achieve a data-transfer-rate higher than the 72Mb/s (with iperf3 I measured around 55-60 Mb/s).